# Why the following codes with only one changed symbol has a different output?

Tags: python, sorting

```
def get_total_score(data):
    data_with_result_score = list(map(lambda x: (*x, x[1] + x[2] + x[3]), data))
    data_with_result_score.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])
    return data_with_result_score

data = [
    ('Amanda', 37, 78, 67),
    ('Patricia', 78, 93, 68),
    ('Marcos', 79, 67, 89),
    ('Dmitry', 67, 68, 100),
    ('Andrey', 100, 78, 76),
    ('Victoria', 93, 69, 96),
]
print(get_total_score(data))
# [('Amanda', 37, 78, 67, 182), ('Patricia', 78, 93, 68, 239), ('Andrey', 100, 78, 76, 254), ('Marcos', 79, 67, 89, 235), ('Victoria', 93, 69, 96, 258), ('Dmitry', 67, 68, 100, 235)]
```

and:

```
def get_total_score(data):
    data_with_result_score = list(map(lambda x: (*x, x[1] + x[2] + x[3]), data))
    data_with_result_score.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1]) #The difference in x[]
    return data_with_result_score

data = [
    ('Amanda', 37, 78, 67),
    ('Patricia', 78, 93, 68),
    ('Marcos', 79, 67, 89),
    ('Dmitry', 67, 68, 100),
    ('Andrey', 100, 78, 76),
    ('Victoria', 93, 69, 96),
]
print(get_total_score(data))
# [('Amanda', 37, 78, 67, 182), ('Marcos', 79, 67, 89, 235), ('Dmitry', 67, 68, 100, 235), ('Patricia', 78, 93, 68, 239), ('Andrey', 100, 78, 76, 254), ('Victoria', 93, 69, 96, 258)]
```

I was expecting what the output will be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second method is correct. After unpacking and inserting the sum, the tuples in data go from four-element tuples to five-element tuples, the indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, the last index being 4.

`x[-1]` means the last element in x, because when evaluated it retrieves the element located at `x[len(x) - 1]`, in this case the length is 5 and the index you need is 4, not 3. Because the number of elements have changed.

Your intention is to sort the students by total scores, so you should use `x[4]` instead of `x[3]`. But the foolproof approach is to use `x[-1]` as it will work for `x` with any length, not just 5.

The following code will also get what you want, but with better efficiency:

```
data = [
    ('Amanda', 37, 78, 67),
    ('Patricia', 78, 93, 68),
    ('Marcos', 79, 67, 89),
    ('Dmitry', 67, 68, 100),
    ('Andrey', 100, 78, 76),
    ('Victoria', 93, 69, 96),
]
print(sorted(((*x, sum(x[1:])) for x in data), key=lambda x: x[-1]))
```

```
[('Amanda', 37, 78, 67, 182), ('Marcos', 79, 67, 89, 235), ('Dmitry', 67, 68, 100, 235), ('Patricia', 78, 93, 68, 239), ('Andrey', 100, 78, 76, 254), ('Victoria', 93, 69, 96, 258)]
```

But I think it is actually more sensible to sort by average instead of total scores, because the number of scores might not be the same, and the average is more indicative than the total.

```
print(sorted(((*x, sum(x[1:])/len(x[1:])) for x in data), key=lambda x: x[-1]))
```

```
[('Amanda', 37, 78, 67, 60.666666666666664), ('Marcos', 79, 67, 89, 78.33333333333333), ('Dmitry', 67, 68, 100, 78.33333333333333), ('Patricia', 78, 93, 68, 79.66666666666667), ('Andrey', 100, 78, 76, 84.66666666666667), ('Victoria', 93, 69, 96, 86.0)]
```